# What does gravity compensation do in flight control?

Tags: flight-controls, stability, control-surfaces

[image]In flight control designs for lateral directional movement, there is a block named "gravity compensation". This block changes yaw rate measurement from "$r$" to "$r-g/Vcos(\theta)sin(\phi)$" before it is sent to the controller. How does this block change the equation of motion?

Comment: can you provide an image example? have you studied the equation of motion?

Comment: I provided an image example

Answer (score 1):

That term is a feedforward.
It simply makes sure that during a turn the rudder will anticipate the need for that $r$ component and thus helps making the turn [coordinated](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/75380/1467).

Since the term is complete (i.e. there is also the $\theta$ component) this will work also for climbing/descending turns.

Comment: It looks like a feedforward. But note that it is fed to the feedback controller. If it was feedforward, it should be added to the output of the feedback. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @shooshool no, it is a feedforward. the fact that is added to $r$ instead of the rudder command does not change its nature. source: I've implemented it several times on our research aircraft.

Comment: Should this feedforward be considered when the controller block is being designed? Or the controller is designed without considering the effect of feedforward and then the feedforward is added?

Comment: @shooshool if it is there, usually the controller is designed assuming that the feedforward is working as intended, i.e. lowering the load on the controller, but that's a different matter not for this stack